# MySQL count + rollup to subtotal a query question

Tags: mysql, sql

My procedure will take the first 100 rows from a table ordered by rank desc.

```
SELECT city FROM table ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0,100
```

Returns:

```
Seattle,
Portland,
Los Angeles,
Portland,
Eugene,
Eugene,
etc...
```

I want to then calculate the frequency by which each city appears in the result set (which has to be a partial set of 100 ordered by rank desc, not the whole table.)

What I want:

```
Portland, 2
Eugene, 2
Seattle, 1
Los Angeles, 1
```

I'm not quite sure how to write that query, please help.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT city, count(*)
FROM
(
  SELECT city FROM table ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 0,100
) as sub
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```